# Generic error: "Error uploading to the iTunes Store" in submission

Tags: java, ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I try to upload my new version to the iTunes Store with Xcode I get error: "Error uploading to the iTunes Store". So I tried with the Application Loader and the details were slightly more specific:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 171: [:
>   Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/rt.jar: integer expression expected
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/rt.jar

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I managed to fix the former problem by "debugging" the Apple software, by namely deleting the offending block at line 171 of iTMSTransporter. Unfortunately the latter problem is more irksome as the file correctly sits in the seached location.

Comment: And I apparently managed to also fix the latter by copying and restoring file rt.jar. It could have been affected by some permissione error. The submission seems to go fine, at least on the Application Loader, Xcode kept on somewhat complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently a lingering problem with the submission by Xcode. Yet submissions by Application Loader works fine at all times.